# Docker: Multiple MySQL instances/containers - second slave time out

Tags: mysql, docker, master-slave

I am very new in using Docker and I wonder if there is a way to allow multiple MySQL instances/containers to run at the same time? I have tried the following:

For the master:

```
docker run -d -v /var/projects/test/db_master:/var/lib/mysql --name
db_master -p 2222:22 -e ROOT_PASS="mypass" tutum/ubuntu:trusty
```

For the slaves:

```
docker run -d -v /var/projects/test/db_slave:/var/lib/mysql --name db_slave -p 2322:22 -e ROOT_PASS="mypass" tutum/ubuntu:trusty

docker run -d -v /var/projects/test/db_slave_5_hours:/var/lib/mysql --name db_slave_5_hours -p 2522:22 -e ROOT_PASS="mypass" tutum/ubuntu:trusty
```

Run MySQL Master and Slave containers:

```
docker run \
   -d \
   --volumes-from db_master \
   -p 3706:3306 \
   -e MYSQL_PASS=admin \
   -e REPLICATION_MASTER=true -e REPLICATION_USER=admin -e REPLICATION_PASS=admin  \
   --name mysql \
   tutum/mysql

docker run -d \
   --volumes-from db_slave \
   -e REPLICATION_SLAVE=true \
   -e MYSQL_PASS=admin \
   -p 3806:3306 \
   --link mysql:mysql \
   --name mysql_slave \
   tutum/mysql

docker run -d \
   --volumes-from db_slave_5_hours \
   -e REPLICATION_SLAVE=true \
   -e MYSQL_PASS=admin \
   -e REPLICATION_DELAY=18000 \
   -p 4006:3306 \
   --link mysql:mysql \
   --name mysql_slave_5_hours \
   tutum/mysql
```

The second slave just times out and exits after 13 attempts of starting MySQL as specified in run.sh and it does not matter which slave I start first.

Thank you in advance.